# Graph Morphism Closed Immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ a morphism between $S$-schemes where $Y$ is a separated $S$-scheme. Therefore the diagonal morphism $Y \to Y \times_S Y$ is a closed immersion.

Let $\Gamma_f = (id,f): X \to X \times_S Y$ the graph morphism.

Why and how to see that $\Gamma_f $ is a closed immersion.

Comment: Can you realise this situation as a fibre product (where the bottom horizontal line is the diagonal morphism and the top one if $\Gamma_f$)?

Comment: Why and how to see that $\Gamma_f $ is a closed immersion.
I suppose that you are mean

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X  @>\Gamma_f  >> Y\times_S X   \\
@VVfV  @VV(id,f)V   \\
Y @>\Delta>> X \times_S Y 
\end{CD}
$$

Is it that what you mean? If yes, why does if prove the claim? Is $(id,f)$ closed immersion?

Comment: Yes, $\Delta$ is a closed embedding by assumption and since closed embeddings are stable under base change it follows that $\Gamma_f$ is also a closed embedding. To see that this diagram is actually a fibre product I guess you can work locally on affine opens where it should be easier and then glue everything together again (set-theoretically is quite intuitive I guess).

Answer (score 2):

Let the structure maps of $X$ and $Y$ as $S$-schemes be $u$ and $v$, respectively, so that $u=v\circ f$.

As mentioned in the comments, we want to check
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{\Gamma_f}>> X\times_SY\\
@V{f}VV @V{f\times Y}VV \\
Y @>{\Delta_Y}>> Y\times_SY
\end{CD}$$
is a fibered product. We may check this locally [the commuting diagram produces a morphism of schemes $X\to Y\times_{Y\times_SY}(X\times_SY)$, and we may check this is an isomorphism locally], so let $U=\mathrm{Spec} R\subset S$ be an affine open set, $W=\mathrm{Spec} B\subset v^{-1}(U)\subset Y$, and $V=\mathrm{Spec} A\subset f^{-1}(W)\subset X$. Now the diagram solely consists of affine schemes:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>{\Gamma_{f|_V}}>> V\times_UW\\
@V{f|_V}VV @V{f|_V\times W}VV \\
W @>{\Delta_Y}>> W\times_UW
\end{CD}$$

Suppose $f\colon V\to W$ is given by $\varphi\colon B\to A$. Then in the category of commutative rings the diagram becomes:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @<{\gamma}<< A\otimes_RB\\
@A{\varphi}AA @A{\varphi\otimes B}AA \\
B @<{\delta}<< B\otimes_RB
\end{CD}$$
where $\gamma(a\otimes b):=a\varphi(b)$ and $\delta(b_1\otimes b_2)=b_1b_2$. Now following the diagram gives $$\varphi\circ\delta(b_1\otimes b_2)=\varphi(b_1b_2)=\varphi(b_1)\cdot\varphi(b_2)=\gamma(\varphi(b_1)\otimes b_2)=\gamma\circ(\varphi\otimes B)(b_1\otimes b_2),$$
so it indeed commutes.

**To show this is a pullback diagram:** We want to show $A\cong B\otimes_{B\otimes_RB}(A\otimes_RB)$. We have maps:

$$A\to B\otimes_{B\otimes_RB}(A\otimes_RB):a\mapsto1\otimes(a\otimes1)$$
and
$$B\otimes_{B\otimes_RB}(A\otimes_RB)\to A:b_1\otimes(a\otimes b_2)\mapsto \varphi(b_1b_2)a.$$
There are a couple of things to check here:

- That the second map is well-defined: Check that $B\times(A\otimes_RB)\to A:(b_1,a\otimes b_2)\mapsto \varphi(b_1b_2)a$ is a well-defined $B\otimes_RB$-bilinear map.
- That these maps are inverses of each other. One composition is obvious: $a\mapsto 1\otimes(a\otimes 1)\mapsto a$. The other direction is:
  \begin{align*}1\otimes(\varphi(b_1b_2)a\otimes 1)&=1\otimes\big((b_1b_2\otimes1)\cdot(a\otimes 1)\big)\\
  &=\big((b_1b_2\otimes1)\cdot1\big)\otimes(a\otimes 1)\\
  &=b_1b_2\otimes(a\otimes 1)\\
  &=\big((1\otimes b_2)\cdot b_1\big)\otimes(a\otimes 1)\\
  &=b_1\otimes\big((1\otimes b_2)\cdot(a\otimes 1)\big)\\
  &=b_1\otimes(a\otimes b_2).
  \end{align*}

Comment: I think the answer is rather incomplete (or at least requires some clarifications): Firstly, why it suffice to work locally here? Secondly, passing to diagram for commutative rings you have shown that the diagram commutes, but not that it's a fibered product / pullback square.

Comment: My bad, I agree. I will try to edit it within the next few hours.